# Add .jar library to apachi cordova - Visual studio 2015

Tags: javascript, android, apache, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I write and andriod cordova project in visual studio 2015 . I need to use a library .jar file that help me to connect to serial port (connected to usb -> otg).
I want to add this jar file as plugin or ... My cordovaCLI version is 6.0.0

Comment: check if Jordan's answer works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906585/visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-add-a-jar-from-3party